# Problem with variable in awk

Tags: awk

I want to replace the text sd in the following command with a variable:

```
lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F  \/ '/sd/ { dsk=substr($1,1,3);dsks[dsk]+=1 } END { for ( i in dsks ) { if (dsks[i]==1) print i } }'
```

I have tried:

```
lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F -v dev=sd \/ '/{print $dev}/ { dsk=substr($1,1,3);dsks[dsk]+=1 } END { for ( i in dsks ) { if (dsks[i]==1) print i } }'
```

but that's not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

The lsblk output, which is piped to awk is this:

```
NAME MOUNTPOINT
sda 
sda1 /boot/efi
sda2 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae467d4-05e9-4aea-8341-0d1524a3ec9c/volume-subpaths/tigera-ca-bundle/calico-kube-controllers/1
sda3 
sdb 
sdc 
sr0
```

expected output is:

```
sdb
sdc
```

So all disks, starting with sd, except the os disk, sda

Comment: Hi Peter and welcome. When asking questions like this, please make sure to include: i) example input (we don't know what `lsblk` returns on your system), ii) desired output. That way we can test our solutions. Also, when there is an error, don't tell us something is "not working" since that really doesn't tell us anything. Instead, show us the exact error message or, if none, describe how the behavior is not what you expected. Finally, it is always good to mention your operating system so we know what you are working with (we support several).

Comment: See also `lsblk -nro name | grep -Eo '^sd[a-z]+' | sort | uniq -u`

Comment: Imagine taking your car to a mechanic and just saying "that's not working" and expecting them to be able to fix it. Exactly the same applies when asking for help to debug problems with your software or when going to a doctor if you're sick. You need to tell us the symptoms. Also, if you don't show us the text you want help writing a tool to parse (i.e. the output of `lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT`) and you don't show us the final output you want from the desired tool given that input then you're making it very much harder than necessary, maybe impossible, for us to be able to best help you

Comment: @terdon, yes, you are right, didn't realize this, added this to the question. Thanks

Comment: You appear to be doing `substr($1,1,3)` to convert `sda1` into `sda` but if you want to use a variable `dev` instead of hard-coding `sd` then is it safe to assume the contents of that variable will also be 2 chars, always with 1 letter then digits after it in the input, and you won't have something like `dev=FOOBAR` with input like `FOOBARabc123 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae467d4...` and then need to convert `FOOBARabc123` into `FOOBARabc` or something else?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, that's working very well, thanks.

Comment: I wonder what you're expecting `/{print $dev}/` to do in that second AWK script

Answer (score 3):

The `-F` option sets the field separator. You cannot put some other option in the middle: `awk -F -v dev=sd \/`. That is actually setting the field separator to the string `-v`:

```
$ awk -F -v 'BEGIN{print FS}'
-v
```

And not even that since the `dev=sd` is parsed as a script that should be run. Anyway, what you want is:

```
awk -F '/' -v dev=sd ' awk script here ' file
```

Next, the `/ /` construct in the context you are using it expects a regular expression. It won't expand variables. Also, awk variables don't start with `$`, only *fields* do. A user-defiend variable is `var` not `$var`. In fact, `$var` actually means "the field whose number is the value stored in `var`". So if `var=6`, then `$var` is `$6`, the value of the 6th field.

Instead, to match against a variable, you need the `~` operator. So, putting all this together, my guess (you haven't shown input or expected output so I can only guess) is that you want something like this:

```
lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | 
  awk -F '/' -v dev=sd  '
    $0 ~ dev { 
     dsk=substr($1,1,3);
     dsks[dsk]+=1 
    } 
    END { 
     for ( i in dsks ) { 
      if (dsks[i]==1) print i 
     }
   }'
```

Comment: @PeterTalen Note that that script could probably be made more robust and/or efficient once we know what your input and expected output look like.

Comment: @Kusalanada, thanks!

Comment: @ed-morton, added it to the question

Comment: @PeterTalen you added some sample input but not the expected output given that input so that's much better but still only half the example AND it's only the sunny day cases - what if `sd` appeared in the middle of `sr0 /foo/bar/thi**sd**isaster/...`, etc.? It's always much easier to write code to match the text you want than to not match similar text you don't want. So think about what the possible rainy day cases are and add those to your sample input/output otherwise you're likely to get a solution that ONLY works for sunny day cases (as is the case with all of the code posted so far).